# Trying to fix email validation for school project

Tags: javascript, html, validation

Hey so uh I have a project due in a few days which requires us to make a contact page where someone can enter a name, email address, subject and message. We need to create javascript to make sure all fields are filled in and that the email is valid.
I have written the HTML for the form, as well as the javascript but I have 2 problems:

1. No error message displays when no message is entered in the memo field
2. The email field will not accept a valid email

I have tried to change the ID tag for the email but it automatically allows me to submit straight away without entering any data, I'm quite stuck.

Yes, they are both in two separate documents.

Note: I have not included all the code for the contact page, just the relevant form.

Thank you so much

Here are the images of my code:

HTML for contact page:
[image]

Javascript for Contact page:

[image]

```js
function checkForm(){
  var isValid = true;
  var name = document.forms['contact']['name'].value;
  var email = document.forms['contact']['emailaddress'].value;
  var emailpattern = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;
  var subject = document.forms["contact"]["subject"].value;
  var textarea = document.forms["contact"]["memo"].value;
  console.log(name, email, subject, textarea);

if(name == ""){
  document.getElementById('namemessage').innerHTML = "PLEASE enter a name";
  isValid = false;
} else {
  document.getElementById('namemessage').style.display = "none";
}

if(!emailpattern.test(emailaddress)){
  document.getElementById('emailmessage').innerHTML = "PLEASE enter a valid email";
  isValid = false;
}
else {
  document.getElementById('emailmessage').style.display = "none";
}


if(subject == ""){
  document.getElementById('subjectmessage').innerHTML = "PLEASE enter a subject";
  isValid = false;
} else {
  document.getElementById('subjectmessage').style.display = "none";
}

if(memo == ""){
  document.getElementById('memomessage').innerHTML = "PLEASE enter your request";
  isValid = false;
} else {
  document.getElementById('memomessage').style.display = "none";
}
  return isValid;
}
```

```html
<main><form action="thankyou.html" name="contact" onsubmit="return checkForm()">
  <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="name">
  <p id="namemessage"></p><br><br>


  <label for="emailaddress">Email Address:</label>
  <input type="text" id="emailaddress">
  <p id="emailmessage"></p><br><br>


  <label for="subject">Subject:</label>
  <input type="text" id="subject"><p id="subjectmessage">
  </p><br><br>


  <label for=memo>Message:</label><br><br>
<textarea id="memo" placeholder = "please type your message here.">
</textarea>
<br><p id="memomessage"></p><br><br>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
</main>
```

Comment: The form has no start tag. The form controls don't have name attributes, which are required for them to be successful. A form control named "name" masks the form's own *name* property.

Comment: @RobG There are start tags in the full document. I have added the name attributes but it does not solve either of my issues. Do you have any other advice?

Comment: Please don't post images of code, only post text. Your issues are simple typos, so I've voted to close the question as it's unlikely to help others.

Answer (score 1):

> No error message displays when no message is entered in the memo field

Because you have:

```
var textarea = document.forms["contact"]["memo"].value;
...
if (memo == "") {
```

Change *textarea* to *memo*.

> The email field will not accept a valid email

Because you have:

```
var email = document.forms['contact']['emailaddress'].value;
...
if (!emailpattern.test(emailaddress)) {
```

Change *emailaddress* to *email*.

Fix those issues and it "works".